# Find List of string in List of strings simplify like in SQL

Tags: c#, sql, compare, contains, except

I am trying to figure out how can I able to find my list of strings in the list of strings.

I found other solutions but most of them are finding only a single word in a string list, but mine is different.

To put it in a simple way to understand, I made a SQL Script that I achieved the objective that I need in C#. Thank you.

```
*;WITH cteFindTheseWords (Word) AS (
    SELECT 'One' UNION ALL
    SELECT 'Two' UNION ALL
    SELECT 'Three' UNION ALL
    SELECT 'Four' 
), cteFindWordsHere (FindHere) AS (
    SELECT 'One Two' UNION ALL
    SELECT 'Earth' UNION ALL
    SELECT 'Land Four' UNION ALL
    SELECT 'The One' UNION ALL
    SELECT 'Hello Wolrd' UNION ALL
    SELECT 'World Everest' UNION ALL
    SELECT 'Then now Two' 
)
SELECT *
FROM cteFindWordsHere a
    JOIN cteFindTheseWords b ON a.FindHere LIKE '%'+ b.Word +'%'*
```

Comment: Follow this to ask a question that can get you better answers 
 - https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: You can foreach elements of the first and then the elements of the second and check if those elements el1.Equals(el1) if they are equal you have match and do what you want as business logic.

Comment: the `{ }` button above the "type your question into" text box can be used for formatting code

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to solve 3 problems here:

1. Test if a string contains a given substring
2. Test the above condition for *any* of multiple substrings
3. Apply this to a *list* of strings

To test whether a given substring (ie. `"One"`) occurs in a given string (ie. "One Two"), you could use [the `string.IndexOf()` method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string.indexof?view=net-6.0#System_String_IndexOf_System_String_):

```
var indexOfSubstring = "One Two".IndexOf("One");
if(indexOfSubstring >= 0){
    // substring was found in string
}
```

To test whether *any* of a list of substrings match the above condition, we can use [the LINQ `Any()` method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.any?view=net-6.0#System_Linq_Enumerable_Any__1_System_Collections_Generic_IEnumerable___0__System_Func___0_System_Boolean__):

```
var substrings = new string[] { "One", "Two", "Three", "Four" };
substrings.Any(s => "One Two".IndexOf(s) >= 0)
```

And finally, to filter a whole list of strings, we can use [the LINQ `Where()` method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.where?view=net-6.0#System_Linq_Enumerable_Where__1_System_Collections_Generic_IEnumerable___0__System_Func___0_System_Int32_System_Boolean__):

```
var strings = new string[] { "One Two", "Earth", "Land Four", "The One", "Hello Wolrd", "World Everest", "Then now Two" };
var substrings = new string[] { "One", "Two", "Three", "Four" };

var filteredList = strings.Where(w => substrings.Any(s => w.IndexOf(s) >= 0)).ToList();
```

---

If a case-**i**nsensitive comparison is desired, pass a `StringComparison` instance to the `IndexOf()` call:

```
var filteredList = strings.Where(w => substrings.Any(s => w.IndexOf(s, StringComparison.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase) >= 0)).ToList();
```

Comment: Great! This works for me! Plenty of explantion. Thanks a lot, dude. You saved me. :)

Comment: @Jog You're welcome! If this answers your question, please consider marking it "accepted" by clicking the checkmark on the left :)

Comment: Why not `Contains`? It's simpler to use than `IndexOf`

Comment: @CaiusJard If the use case is always ordinal case-sensitive comparison then yes, `Contains()` is the "simpler" choice. Reason I prefer `IndexOf()` is the opportunity to specify the `StringComparison` type, as shown at the bottom of the answer :)

Comment: Also note that this code is subtly different to the SQL posted, both in terms of width and length of output

Comment: Oh.. You must do a lot of work with .net framework then, StringComparison for Contains has been a thing since netcore 2.1 but sadly still missing in 4.8 I think.. I suppose it also helps avoid confusion with IEnumerable.Contains which would get somewhat confusing LINQing a list of string

Comment: @CaiusJard I do, sadly, happen to do a lot of work on platforms where .NET FX is the only available option :)